# zclip not working (No console errors)

Tags: jquery, clipboard, zclip

this is my code.
Dont know what wrong in it but not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#copy').click(function(e) {  
        alert("inn");
        $("#dynamic").zclip({
            path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:$('input#dynamic').val(),
            afterCopy:function(){
                alert("immm");      
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="dynamic" value="abcd" />
<div id="copy">CLICK</div>
```

Comment: What seems to be the error?, what is not working more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice/work, since zclip has default click-event as eventhandler:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#copy").zclip({
        path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('input#dynamic').val(),
        afterCopy:function(){
            alert("immm");      
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, if i removed click event the alert in the "aftercopy" is coming. But when i try to paste, nothing coming..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
zclip only works on server. So you need to run it on localhost or server.